# If every orthogonal projection of a manifold $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ on a plane is a disk, then $M$ is a sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, submanifold

Given  a 2-d manifold $M$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and a plane $\alpha$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Assume that $M$ is smooth and has convex, simply-connected inner part.

If we project $M$ orthogonally onto $\alpha$ we always get a round disk (maybe in different diameter as $\alpha$ changes), can we prove or disprove that $M$ is a sphere?

Comment: If you allow disconnected manifolds then two concentric spheres will project on any plane as *closed* disk. I assume that the geometry of the projection, i.e. roundedness of the disk, is also implicitly required in your question. and not just projection being diffeomorphic to a closed disk

Comment: This question is a certain 3d generalisation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_tetrahedron . but generalized in certain sense

Comment: Given the comment by @Physor, you may try addding a constraint that each point on the disk interior has exactly 2 pre-images, and each point on the disk frontier exactly one.

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni: Thanks, I tried to fix the problem in another way: make the manifold have convex & simply connected inner part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Partial answer

One can prove that the radius is the same for all planes.

Take any plane $\alpha_1$. the projection $\pi_{\alpha_1}(M)$ being a closed disk $D_1$ means that the $M$ is a subset of the (solid) cyliner $C_1 = \pi_{\alpha_1}^{-1}(D_1)$ prependicular to $\alpha_1$ with radius $R_1$, as that of the $D_1$. Take any other nonparallel plane $\alpha_2$ and its cylinder $C_2 = \pi_{\alpha_2}^{-1}(D_2)$. The projection of $C_1$ on $\alpha_2$ is an infinite strip of width $2R_1$. This projection should contain the disk $D_2$, i.e. $\pi_{\alpha_2}(M) \subset \pi_{\alpha_2}(C_1)$, since $M \subset C_1$. This implies $2R_1 \ge 2R_2$. Similarly $2R_2 \ge 2R_1$.

Now if the radius of these projection is $R$ then any point $p$ not in the sphere $S^2$, with radius $R$, will be a distance $l \neq R$ from the center $O$ of $M$, which is found by finding the intersection of two lines prependicular to the centers of two nonparallel disks $D_1, D_2$.

- If $l \ge R$ then there is a plane $\alpha$ through $p$ and $C$ where the projection $\pi_\alpha(p)$ of $p$ is not in the disk $D$, i.e. $\|\pi_\alpha(p) - \pi_\alpha(O)\| = l \ge R$, a contradiction.
- It remains to show a contradiction for the case $l \le R$. ...

**Better Argument:**

One can conclude that $M \subset B_R = \bigcap_{\alpha: \text{ 2-d plane}} \pi_\alpha^{-1}(\pi_\alpha(M))$, where $B_R$ is the *closed* ball of radius $R$. Since $M$ is a 2d-manifold then necessarily $\partial B_R \subset M$. Otherwise $\exists p(\partial B_R \ni p \notin M)$ and a plane $\alpha$ through the center and $p$ and the $\pi_\alpha(M)$ is not a closed disk.

Since $M$ is, as $\partial B_R$, connected and 2-d, then with by the fact $\partial B_R \subset M$ there "must" be some theorem from topology that concludes that they are same.

Comment: I think for $l < R$ part you need to use the property that inner of $M$ is convex.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but at least one can conclude that $M$ is a subset of a closed ball $B_R$ (of radius $R$). Now since $M$ it is 2d-manifold, then $\partial B_R \subset M$, where $\partial B_R$ is the boundary of $B_R$ otherwise there is a point $\partial B_R \ni p \notin M$ and a plane $\alpha$ through the center and $p$ and the $\pi_\alpha(M)$ is not a clsed disk

Answer (score 1):

Note that the question was raised on mathoverflow and an answer was validated, although somewhat terse and with hypotheses less precise than here.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/is-the-sphere-the-only-surface-with-circular-projections-or-can-we-deduce-a-sp